# Optimizing Diwali Lights problem in C

Tags: optimization, c, programming-challenge, combinatorics, time-limit-exceeded

I was trying to solve the [Diwali Lights challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diwali-lights) on HackerRank.

> #### Problem Statement
>
> On the eve of Diwali, Hari is decorating his house with a serial light
>   bulb set. The serial light bulb set has N bulbs placed sequentially on
>   a string which is programmed to change patterns every second. If
>   atleast one bulb in the set is on at any given instant of time, how
>   many different patterns of light can the serial light bulb set
>   produce?
>
> Note: Lighting two bulbs `*-*` is different from `**-`
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line contains the number of test cases T, T
>   lines follow.  Each line contains an integer N, the number of bulbs in
>   the serial light bulb set.
>
> #### Output Format
>
> Print the total number of patterns modulo 10<sup>5</sup>
>
> #### Constraints
>
> 1 <= T <= 1000
>   0 < N < 10<sup>4</sup>
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 2
> 1
> 2
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 1
> 3
> ```

The Code I had written is

```
#include<stdio.h>
# define MAX 10000 // assuming we need first 100 rows
unsigned long long triangle[MAX + 1][MAX + 1];

void makeTriangle() {
    int i, j;

    // inietialize the first row
    triangle[0][0] = 1; // C(0, 0) = 1

    for(i = 1; i < MAX; i++) {
        triangle[i][0] = 1; // C(i, 0) = 1
        for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            triangle[i][j] = (triangle[i - 1][j - 1] + triangle[i - 1][j]) %100000;
        }
    }
}

unsigned long long C(int n, int r) {
    return triangle[n][r];
}
/*long long C(int N, int R)
    {
        if(R > N/2) R = N - R;
        int i;
        unsigned long long ans = 1;
        for(i=1; i<=R; i++)
        {
            ans *= N-R+i;
            ans /=i;
        }
    //  printf("N=>%d R=>%d ANS=>%lld\n", N, R, ans);
        return ans;
    }
 */
int main()
{
    makeTriangle();
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T--)
    {
        int N;
        scanf("%d", &N);
        //  int copy = N;
        int i;
        unsigned long long int answer =0;
        switch (N)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("1\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("3\n");
            break;
        default:
        {   
            int limit = N%2==0? (N /2) -1:(N/2);    // Caluculate nCr till N/2 and multiply by 2
            int n_even =0;
            if( N%2 ==0)            // calculate nC(n/2) only when N is Even
            {
                n_even = C(N,N/2);  
            }
            for(i=1;i<=limit;i++)
            {
                answer +=(2*C(N,i));
                answer %= 100000;
            }
            printf("%lld\n", (answer+ 1+ n_even) % 100000); //+1 is for nCn which is 1 always 
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The answer is pretty straightforward as it can be obtained by the summation of nCr. But there were a few hiccups when I tried to implement the same.

In my first attempt I had used the commented function C(N,R) to calculate the nCr each and every time for all the test cases. But this approach gave me a TLE error. So I decided I'd compute the values for nCr for all the values in with the makeTriangle() function and then whenever I called this function it would return me the computed value by looking up the array in O(1) time.

However, even this approach gave me a Time limit Exceeded error. Hence I was wondering if there could be any other optimizations that I could do with this code or a possible different approach to this problem :)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. There are \$2^N\$ patterns, and only one of them has no bulbs on.

Comment: @vnp Yes, I checked and the answer is indeed 2^N patterns. Could you tell me how you arrived at that expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @vnp has pointed out, each bulb can have two states, so the number of possibilities is \$2^N\$. However, the state where all bulbs are off is prohibited, so subtract one, and is the answer is simply \$(2^N -1) \mod 10^5\$.

The tricky part of the problem is that \$2^{{10}^4} -1\$ is a very large number to work with, so calculating \$(2^N -1) \mod 10^5\$ is a non-trivial problem.

Comment: The key thing to note from here is that \$a^b \; \text{mod} \; n\$ has a well known method.

Comment: @Veedrac Could you explain what the method is? Is it Binary Exponentiation?

Comment: @thebenman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method